# How to compare a JavaScript string containing special characters to a string encoded by PHP's htmlentities()?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data from a MySQL database using PHP and then echoing it out to the page. I encode the string using `htmlentities()` to avoid XSS problems. I need to compare the text that a user writes in a textbox with the data echo'd out, but I've run into a problem. Suppose the data in the database is `le beau-frère`, then the data that get's echo'd out looks like this:

```
le beau-fr&egrave;re
```

The data that the user enters looks like this:

```
le beau-frère
```

If I try to directly compare the two strings, they obviously are not the same.

How can I convert one of the strings to the format of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use innerText - it will convert the htmlentities data from

```
le beau-fr&egrave;re
```

to

```
le beau-frère
```

---

If you've echoed the saved data directly to javascript, then in order to use the innerText workaround,you would have to save it to a div using innerHTML and fetch it again using innerText. e.g.

```
<div id="foo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'le beau-fr&egrave;re';
var savedData = document.getElementById('foo').innerText;
</script>
```

---

If you want to keep it nice and tidy, I would create a temporary div in JavaScript and then remove it afterwards.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a more direct method, but this works well, so thanks!